# Add brackets to string in data frame

Tags: r, rscript

I've got this data frame called df:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
String1   A
String2   A
String3   B
String4   A
...       ...
```

Every string in ColumnA have different lenght. I want to put values from ColumnA in brackets if value in ColumnB == A in the same row. If the value in ColumnB == B I want to add square brackets instead. So it will looks like:

```
ColumnA     ColumnB
(String1)   A
(String2)   A
[String3]   B
(String4)   A
...         ...
```

What's the best way to achive that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`

```
df1$ColumnA <- with(df1, ifelse(ColumnB == "A", paste0("(", ColumnA, ")"), 
                                                    paste0("[", ColumnA, "]")))
> df1$ColumnA

#[1] "(String1)" "(String2)" "[String3]" "(String4)"
```

Or if there are values other than `A` and `B` in `ColumnB`, you can use multiple `ifelse`

```
df1$ColumnA <- with(df1, ifelse(ColumnB == "A", paste0("(", ColumnA, ")"), 
                       ifelse(ColumnB == "B", paste0("[", ColumnA, "]"), ColumnA)))
> df1$ColumnA

#[1] "(String1)" "(String2)" "[String3]" "(String4)"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried that and it doesn't work. Nothing has changed.

Comment: What is the name of your dataframe? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @TityBoi If you have a `factor` class, then convert to `character` i.e. `ifelse(as.character(ColumB) == "A", ...`

Comment: Bet they didn't assign the result back, as often happens. @TityBoi did you try `df$ColumnA<-...` (replace the dots with the line in the answer)? Otherwise the columns won't be replaced.

Comment: That might be the case. Updated the answer. Thanks @nicola .

Comment: Yeah, that was the case :) Thanks a lot!